# JAXB add additional static root element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I have the following POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SessionStartInput")
public class SessionStartInput {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected SessionStartInputHeader header;
    @XmlElement(name = "Parameters", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected SessionStartInputParameters parameters;
  ...
}
```

Which generates:

```
<SessionStartInput>
<Header></Header>
<Parameters></Parameters>
</SessionStartInput>
```

I want to generate:

```
  <SessionStartInput>
    <Input>
      <Header></Header>
      <Parameters></Parameters>
    <Input>
</SessionStartInput>
```

Adding an additional Input wrapper, is there some sort XML annotation that can do this? I've checked `@XmlElements` but this would mean altering the structure of the POJO. is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Simple, use an [element wrapper](http://kodejava.org/how-to-generate-a-wrapper-element-around-xml-representation-in-jaxb/).

Comment: @BoristheSpider element wrapper: The property must be a collection property, my header is not a collection which would mean i need to modify the pojo structure?

Comment: You're going to have to change your POJO structure to accommodate this, by introducing an intermediary class which contains the `header` and `parameters` fields.

Comment: @skaffman just wanted to confirm is this normal to alter the POJO? I had gotten this pojo from a wsimport from a client wsdl, i just find it odd that I need to alter the POJO to make the ws call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing the POJO to accommodate the change in xml data