# Jaxb how to create xml element container for other xml element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have some class:

```
public class Human{
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String patronymic;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    //..
}
```

I want marshall this class to some xml:

```
<human>
   <fio>
        <lastname></lastname>
        <firstname></firstname>
        <patronymic></patronymic>
   </fio>
   <dateOfBirth><dateOfBirth>
</human>
```

What annotation is used to create pseudo-container fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at xml element wrapper:

http://kodejava.org/how-to-generate-a-wrapper-element-around-xml-representation-in-jaxb/

But i think for your case have to go with:

```
public class Human{
   private Object Fio;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    //..
}

public class Fio{
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String patronymic;
}
```

Comment: And how can I do it without creating a new class FIO? The whole purpose in this.

Comment: dont think you can: i had been searching for the answer as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469194/jaxb-add-additional-static-root-element do update me if you do find it :p